# EL&U Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a moderator, would you be interested in having your own EL&U contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out to friends, colleagues, and family members.

Below is a mockup:

<sub>(click on image to see full res version)</sub>

[image: EL&U moderator cards]

Of course email, Twitter, phone# are optional. They can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: Cool! I wish I was a mod now ahah :D

Comment: Maybe front and back should have been the other way around. But who am I to judge? :))

Comment: The cards look great! Wow, I didn't notice until now. And of course, I echo the sentiment of @Alenanno ;#) Seriously, whomever did the work on these, Jin I guess, did a very nice job!

Comment: @FeralOink thank you, glad you're enjoying them. I did the design, but I give much credit to moo.com, whom we use for all of our cards. Their cards great quality. I highly recommend them!

Comment: @Jin I've noticed moo.com actually! Its been awhile, but I would spend more time than I want to admit just looking at their designs online. I could never make up my mind what to get, I liked everything. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

OK, the cards are now available -- all current moderators were mailed a link to the form to customize the cards. Enjoy!